# jquery, how to check if class is loaded. Then change function to hide after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a sript that will allow a user to click on a div to make a http request. The main purpose, over show/hide, is to cut down on http requests as the content is only loaded when the user requests it.

My function is below and appears to work corerctly. But I now need to "loop" the function, or make an if statement?

The purpose of this is to allow the user to click the same div to show and hide the content.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.windguru').click(function () {
        $('.loader-content').addClass('loader')
        alert('loader has been shown')
        $('.windguru-content').load("http://adamtoms.co.uk/site/windguru1.html", function () {
            alert('windguru content loaded, now remove loader')
            $('.loader-content').removeClass('loader')
            alert('now i want to click windguru and hide the content/loop the function')
        });
    });
});
```

My go at the if statement:

```
$(".windguru").click(function() {


if ($(.windguru-content).val() = 0) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.windguru').click(function () {
        $('.loader-content').addClass('loader')
        alert('loader has been shown')
        $('.windguru-content').load("site/windguru1.html", function () {
            alert('windguru content loaded, now remove loader')
            $('.loader-content').removeClass('loader')
        });
    });
});

}


// Else if the value is anything else
else {
    $(.windguru-content).hide();
}

});
```

Here is a Jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/CeKKx/2/

any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!
Many Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes around your selector and `.length` instead of `.val`

```
if ($(".windguru-content").length) {
```

instead of

```
if ($(.windguru-content).val() = 0) {
```

Plus, in your else write

```
$(".windguru-content").hide();
```

On first load, use css to hide it.

```
.windguru-content {
    display:none;
}
```

Complete code:

```
$(".windguru").click(function () {
    if (!$(".windguru-content").is(':visible')) {
        $('.loader-content').addClass('loader');
        alert('loader has been shown')
        $('.windguru-content').load("site/windguru1.html", function () {
            alert('windguru content loaded, now remove loader');
            $('.loader-content').removeClass('loader');
        });
        $('.windguru-content').toggle();
    } else {
        $('.windguru-content').toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Krishna, there must be another error in the code as its not working? Here is the updated: http://jsfiddle.net/CeKKx/5/

Comment: in your else correct this `$(".windguru-content").hide();`. Also, I'm not completely sure of your script, since you're using a click event inside a click event and a document.ready wrapper. Hard to understand what is expected except to fix the obvious syntax errors.

Comment: thanks Krishna, apologies for the poorly written script, im new to this.

Could the document ready wrapper be removed? It was left in from an old version of this code?

The end goal is to have the user click "windguru (click here)", load the resource. Then click again on "windguru (click here)" and hide the loaded resource.

I have updated the JS fiddle the best I can. http://jsfiddle.net/CeKKx/17/

Comment: @atoms - see if this makes any sense. It toggles `$('.windguru-content')` http://jsfiddle.net/CeKKx/19/

Comment: @Krishna that looks more like it. However it doesnt seem to be working. If i remove line 10 the content doesnt dissapear. But on clicking "wind guru" the content just reloads. It might be easier to see this in action? r.adamtoms.co.uk. (look in the footer, resizing the viewport to mobile).
really appreciate the help/time so far!

Comment: try this `if (!$(".windguru-content").is(':visible')) {`. add a `!` in the if condition http://jsfiddle.net/CeKKx/20/

Comment: @Krishna thats perfect thank you so much! There is a slight problem being, you have to click twice to start the script? Am going to try work out whats been done with the code, I know ive already asked alot but, dont suppose you would mind explaining it?
Thank again!

Comment: @atoms - you have to hide `windguru-content` on page load. I've updated my answer. `<div class="windguru-content" style="display:none">Windguru content</div>` or use CSS to hide it.

Comment: @atoms - glad to help. please upvote and accept as answer when you get a chance.

Comment: @Krishna thanks again for this. If you dont mind I have one question, im completely stumped.
it works fine for "windguru" but the same with a facebook iframe fails to reload. I had the same problem with an earlier solution, again thought it could be down to the facebook content in the iframe.
i can create a jsfiddle or if you dont mind take a look at r.adamtoms.co.uk (footer)
If this isnt too much trouble, cheers!

Comment: @atoms - making a fiddle would definitely help. but again it may be an issue with facebook iframe or the way its being loaded.

Comment: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/HfVDD/ for facebook. Exactly the same as whats on my side. Regarding JSfiddle I'm not sure how to get external src to load, never seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotes in selectors:

```
if ($(".windguru-content").length)
```

and in else

```
 $('.windguru-content').hide();
```